# Wordpress custom hook

Tags: php, wordpress, action, hook

The problem occurs with the fact that I do not know the anatomy of WordPress(it is a first time i'm working with WP), and the task should be solved urgently. I developed a plugin for openID authorization by one of non-popular openID provider. I developed plugin as though it calls main function on 'init' hook. So no one non-authorised user can access any page of site. But task is that i must have "authorise" link on my index page and authorisation must be performed just right after clicking to this link. I tryed to solve problem using custom hook.

I added following to my plugins main file (it is a class function)

```
public function m_authenticate(){
    do_action('m_authenticate');
}
```

Than added an action like that

```
add_action('m_authenticate', array(&$this, 'mAuthenticate'), 7);
```

Here `mAuthenticate` is a function which redirects to openID provider for auth.
After that i created a php script with this hook

```
<?php
m_authenticate();
```

But on calling this script by browser, it occurs an error that script cannot find a function `m_authenticate()`. IF i require script in which `m_authenticate()` is defined, then it occurs an error with other lines of this script, for e.g. `cannot find function` on line

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('some_func', 'addNewWordPressAdmin'));
```

Pls, help with advise how to make seperate page with this openID functionality. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this problem. Here you have the plugin with the class:

`<?php
/* Plugin Name: WP Test */`

`class MyAuthHookClass {`

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('m_authenticate', array( $this, 'mAuthenticate') );
}

public function mAuthenticate() {
    echo "<h1>My Auth</h1>";
}

public static function m_authenticate(){
    do_action('m_authenticate');
} }
```

`new MyAuthHookClass();`

And in theme structure I put the hook in `header.php`:

`<?php if(class_exists('MyAuthHookClass')) MyAuthHookClass::m_authenticate(); ?>`